# Using the HornetQ standalone server

Tags: java, maven, hornetq

I downloaded the 2.5.0 source, and built it by cd'ing to the hornetq-master directory and running mvn clean install (I've also tried mvn clean package). The build reported a success.

According to the 2.4.0 manual, which is the newest I found,

> "In the distribution you will find a directory called bin.
>
> cd into that directory and you will find a Unix/Linux script called
>   run.sh and a windows batch file called run.bat"

If I go to hornetq-master/distribution/hornetq/src/main/resources/bin, I see those files. I don't see any kind of target directory, which I would have expected after a build.

If I execute run.bat, I get an error "Could not find or load main class org.hornetq.cli.HornetQ".

If I look at the hornetq.cmd file, it appears to be trying to use a classpath of %HORNETQ_HOME%\lib, which in my case would be hornetq-master/distribution/hornetq/src/main/resources/lib, which doesn't exist.

So, I assume I'm building this incorrectly. Can somebody tell me how it should be built?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like "distribution" in the manual here is referring to the official distributed .zip file, not something built from source.